# CWBZZ5008 Security error occurred when attempting to connect to system

Tags: asp-classic, transactions, ibm-midrange

We have an ASP Classic *legacy web application*, which is hosted in Windows Server 2003 in IIS, that connect in our database server, which is an **[AS/400](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System_i)**. We've just currently upgrade our database server from *v5r4m0* to *v6r1m0*, so we install an [update](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/software/access/windows/supportedos.html) in our Web Server to connect to the new database server and change all the connection string to the proper database server.

We have this code in our ASP Classic site:

```
set objConn2 = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn2.open connStringGlobal

objConn2.BeginTrans

if rsCheck.eof then
    objConn2.execute(InsertQuery)
    objConn2.execute(InsertQueryRCDREF)
    objConn2.execute(UpdateQuery)
end if

objConn2.CommitTrans

if err.number <> 0 then
    session("errMsg") = "An error occured while processing your request. Please try again. <br><br>[Error Description : " & err.Description & "]<br><br>" & InsertQuery & "<br><br>" & UpdateQuery & "<br><br>" & InsertQueryRCDREF
    objConn2.RollBackTrans  
    objConn2.close
    set objConn2 = nothing
    response.Redirect(request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER"))
else    
    objConn2.close
    set objConn2 = nothing
    response.Redirect("default.asp?p=pending")
end if
```

But it throws an error in the `objConn2.BeginTrans` line which is:

> **CWBZZ5008 Security error occurred** when attempting to connect to system

What happen here is that the connection is opened and the line with `objConn2.execute` is executed, the data are inserted in our database eventhough it goes through the rollback transaction and close connection and shows the error message in the UI.

Here's what we have tried so far:

- Replace the connection string server name to the IP address of the database server
- Check all the *legacy* codes if there has an un-closed connection

But still we have no luck. This site is currently on production, which is stopped because of this error, so we really need to fix this and were already trying to fix this for days. Please we really need help.

---

Our other site which run in the same server and also in ASP Classic that connect to the same database server with transaction works fine, only this site with this code throws an error.

Comment: I would expect that error would be on the line `objConn2.open`. Have you checked the database providers on the server? Maybe need to update them? I see a few sources pointing in this direction. Check [this](http://www.connectionstrings.com/as-400) for more info on providers.

Comment: @GuidoGautier Yes, we actually use that same site as a reference. The other `objConn.open` in our site that uses the same `connStringGlobal` global variable is working fine. Only this one with transaction throws an error.

Comment: why put those steps in a stored procedure including the transaction part and call the stored procedure instead? maybe it'll return the same problem, but maybe not

Comment: What database server are you using? SQL? I haven't seen a conn.BeginTrans method before ...

Comment: @MikeMurko We are using DB2 in AS/400 database server and the connector for that database server (iSeries) for ASP classic. We already solved this problem by journaling the tables. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because the migrated tables from the old database server to the new database server doesn't have any journal yet so the error occur when using the transaction.

> **A journal maintains an audit trail of transactions and database changes.** Transaction logs and Database change logs are used, a transaction log records all the essential data for each transactions, including data values, time of transaction and terminal number. A database change log contains before and after copies of records that have been modified by transactions. - *[wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_processing_system)*

Answer (score 0):

In classic ASP and MS SQL changing the connection string from:

```
con.ConnectionString = _
 "DRIVER={SQL Server}"  & _
 ";Server=" & {sqlserver} & _
 ";initial catalog=" & {dbname} & _
 ";" & {uidpwd}
```

to:

```
con.ConnectionString = _
  "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB.1" & _
  ";DATA SOURCE=" & {sqlserver} & 
  ";DATABASE=" & {dbname} & _
  ";" & {uidpwd}
```

solved the con.BeginTrans error for me. The only change is in the form of the connection string, the parameters being the same.